# Updating a JAR file with DotNetZip results in corrupt archive?

Tags: c#, jar, format, dotnetzip

I'm trying to update (add/modify files) an existing JAR file, and this code (using the DotNetZip library) results in the archive being "corrupted", I cannot open it with WinRAR as a ZIP or a JAR:

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("/path/to/jar", FileMode.Open))
{
    ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(fs);
    fs.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    zip.Save(fs);
}
```

Can anyone tell me what the difference between the ZIP and JAR format is, exactly? I was under the impression it was simply the ZIP format with the manifest as the first entry in the file, which is apparently not the case. Is there an existing (C#) library I can use to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [JAR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAR_%28file_format%29) is *binary compatible* with a ["standard"] ZIP archive. Only the optional Manifest file is prescribed, but this will not cause a "corrupt archive".

I believe one (or both) of these is happening:

1. It is not *truncating* the file so there is "garbage" left at the end.
2. The actual "Read" is lazy and the latter "Save" might mess up the data before it has been correctly read.

(Zipping it to a *new* file would allow this to be verified.)

Comment: I'm not sure which issue it was, but you were correct. I solved the issue in my production code by saving the ZipFile to a MemoryStream, closing & nulling the ZipFile's file stream, nulling the ZipFile, and then writing the MemoryStream to the final destination.

You saved the day, I thought all my hours of work were wasted, thanks so much!